# Linux namespaces: Enforce unshare sandbox on user login

Tags: linux, sandbox

Is there a reliable way to enforce every login of a certain Linux user to use isolate it's namespaces by `unshare`, like eg. the user had executed

```
   unshare -n  -p -U -C -f -m --mount-proc bash
```

on every login, wether he/she comes by ssh, su or the system is running services in their name?